# Unable to Use -json Flag with Nuclei for JSONL Output

Tags: json, security, command-line

I'm currently utilizing [Nuclei](https://github.com/projectdiscovery/nuclei) and attempting to use the `-json` flag to get the output in JSONL format. However, I receive an error stating `flag provided but not defined: -json`.

The command I'm using is:

```
nuclei -u <target_url> -t <templates_path> -json
```

i've also used that i found on [ProjectDiscovery nuclei video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIGLE16fRfE&ab_channel=ProjectDiscovery)

```
nuclei -tags tech -u <target_url> -json
```

and even some workaround but of course it didn't work as well

```
nuclei -tags tech -u <target_url> -json -o output.json
```

Nuclei's documentation states that it supports a variety of output options, including `-json` for JSONL format output, but it seems like the flag is not recognized in the version `v2.9.15` that I'm using with templates version `v9.6.4`.

Here’s a brief overview of the output options stated in the documentation:

```
-json                         write output in JSONL(ines) format
```

Has anyone encountered this issue, and if so, is there a workaround or solution available? Is the `-json` flag available in a different version, or is there an alternative approach to get the output in a structured format like JSON?

Thanks for any assistance or insights!

Answer (score 1):

Nuclei now uses -j for standard json output. Here's the current [usage](https://github.com/projectdiscovery/nuclei):

```
-j, -jsonl                    write output in JSONL(ines) format
-je, -json-export string      file to export results in JSON format
-jle, -jsonl-export string    file to export results in JSONL(ine) format
```

Comment: I double-checked the docs and found out you were right! Thanks for the help anyway!